# Access to an object's fields is only permitted within its methods in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to modify the cluster methods of the phytree object in matlab. After modifying it, I change the name to cluster_second. Then, when I run the function, I got the error saying that

```
Access to an object's fields is only permitted within its methods.
```

I understand what is going on here. Because I need to use tr.tree, and it is a field of the phytree object which can only be accessed within that phytree object's method. Obviously, cluster_second does not satisfy that condition. Can anyone help me out with this? Many thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what your actual question is or what you're trying to do. Why do you need access to `tr.tree`? Show your code. What can you not do with the default methods (`methods(tr)`) such as `get`, `set`, etc.? For example, `get(tr,'Pointers')` seems to return the input `B` if `tr = phytree(B);`. Internally, this is what `tr.tree` is initialized to.

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind reply. I only need to add sequence frequency  to the code. I plan to change the default code, where tr.tree is used (which part I do not need to change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your `cluster_second` method to be a method of `phytree`, put  the file `cluster_second.m` into the directory `\toolbox\bioinfo\bioinfo\@phytree`. All `phytree` objects will then have an additional method `cluster_second` (as well as the original `cluster` method).

It's possible that you may also be able to put it into a different folder named `@phytree`, as long this `@phytree` folder is on your path. I'm afraid I don't have Bioinformatics Toolbox on my current machine to test that, though.

Comment: I do not have permissions to save cluster_second to the directory you mentioned. So I tried it for your second method. It seems like it does not work here.

Comment: Is it a way to get the tr.dist just like getting tr.tree with get(tr, 'pointers') ?